# Node js with mongodb get values from different tables at a time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am just newbie in node js and mongo db. I have taken two models for event one is for event data and another is for event packages. So the model for event looks like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

const EventSchema = new Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  eventname: {
    type: String,
    required : true,
  },
  eventdesc: {
    type: String,
    required : true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);
```

and the model for packages looks like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

const PackageSchema = new Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  eventpackages: {
    type: Object,
    required : false,
  },
  event: { 
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'Event'
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Package', PackageSchema);
```

Here is my event router file where I am getting the list and details for the event

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Event = require('../../model/event.model');
const Package = require('../../model/package.model');


/* GET ALL EVENTS */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Event.find(function (err, events) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(events);
  });
});

/* GET SINGLE EVENT BY ID */
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Event.findById(req.params.id, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(post);
  });

  // Package.find({'event': req.params.id}, function (err, post) {
  //   if (err) return next(err);
  //     res.json(post);
  // });
});

/* SAVE EVENT */

router.post('/', function(req, res, next)  {

let event =  new Event ({
          _id             : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
          eventname       : req.body.eventname,
          eventdesc       : req.body.eventdesc        
      });
        event.save((err) => {
        if(err) {
          if( err.errors ) {
            if( err.errors.eventname ) {
              res.json({ success: false, message: err.errors.eventname.message });
            }
            else {
              if( err.errors.eventdesc ) {
                res.json({ success: false, message: err.errors.eventdesc.message });
              }
            }
          }
          else {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Could not save Event. Error: ', err });
          }
        }
        else {
          let package = new Package({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            event: event._id,
            eventpackages  : req.body.sections,
          });

          package.save(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json({ success: true, message: 'Event saved'});
        });
        }
      });
    });

/* UPDATE EVENT */
router.put('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Event.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});

/* DELETE EVENT */
router.delete('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Event.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Now when I make listing or details page for events I want to get all the details of events with its package which has been made reference id in the package schema. So can some one tell me how should I make a query for the reference table so that I will get all the data at a time and show them

Comment: Correct me if I understood it wrong, an `event` should have a `package` but not a `package` with `event`. You should be probably referring to the `Package` inside `EventSchema`

Comment: Yes, an event should have a package.

Comment: [Mongo $lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). You can use this feature to get data from two different collections.

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score -1):

First of all you have to store the corresponding package._id in event result and than you have to query by passing both the ids.